# load random image from array to a css background

Tags: javascript, css

I am a js newbie. I Have looked for answers to this particular issue but have not found an answer yet in this forum or others, so sorry if it's here and I missed it. I have a script that works for loading a random image from an array to an id element placed directly in the html when the page loads.

I'm trying to see if I can get it to do the same thing but do it for a background image in a id element in a css file. I have firebug and it doesn't give me any error messages with this but it doesn't work either.

```
window. onload = choosePic;

var myPix = new
Array("images/image1.gif", "images/image2.gif");

function choosePic() {
    randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * myPix.length));
    document.getElementById("headerAnimation").style.backgroundImage.src = myPix[randomNum];
}
```

Comment: remove the `.src`, as in, it should just be `.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://image.com/example.png')"`

Answer (score 3):

You have it almost right.

```
window.onload = choosePic;

var myPix = new Array("images/image1.gif", "images/image2.gif");

function choosePic() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * myPix.length));
    document.getElementById("headerAnimation").style.backgroundImage =
        "url(" + myPix[randomNum] + ")";
}
```

Comment: Hey this works! Thank you So Much! So the backgroundImage is equal to "url(with some parameters)". I think one of the problems with the way I looked at it was I wanted to change the css property but javascript is really overriding the property. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, also you were looking at it as being more granular than it is. There is a `style.background` and a `style.backgroundImage` because there are CSS properties `background` and `background-image`. But you were trying to access `style.backgroundImage.src` which doesn't exist (there's no `background-image.src` property in CSS. :) ) Remember what you're setting is a CSS property, no more, no less. Which means you need to remember `url()` or `px` or whatever would go in the CSS if you were writing a .css file.

Comment: Excellent! I will try playing around with that some more. Hopefully it will become clearer with practice. Thanks again!